# Mouse scrollable carousel , example provided

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

Any idea or example on making a mouse scrollable carousel , scroll horizontally

This may be bad user experience, but it will be quite handy for Magic Mouse and Multi Touch touchpad user.

https://www.google.com/search?q=jack+sparrow&oq=jack+sparrow&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.2398j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=tim+burton&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAGOovnz8BQMDgxoHsxCHfq6-QVZahaESmGVelGKuxReQWlScnxecmZJanlhZLF_H9e1QNr-bp2NobZud2ctPmUdfAQADgChOQwAAAA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mousewheel plugin for that [Mousewheel Demo](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/)